# Jest Coverage Reporting: Aggregate Sub Directories

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

The coverage report outputs:

```
               Statements Covered
/Parent         1/1
/Parent/Child0  0/3
/Parent/Child1  2/5
```

I would like it to output:

```
               Statements Covered
/Parent         3/9
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I simply need to limit the scope of the coverage report using --collectCoverageFrom

npx jest --coverage --collectCoverageFrom="src/Parent/**/*"